# Key fallback in NHibernate LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

H!

I'm coding a message store with locale fallback for a web application which uses NHibernate over a SQL database. For example, the result of `store.Get("Greet", "fr-ca-on")` would be the best-match value from this data (`fr-ca`):

```
Key    Locale    Message
-----  ------    --------
Greet            Hello
Greet  fr        Bonjour!
Greet  fr-ca     Âllo!
Greet  fr-ca-qc  Âllo toi!
```

I've tried various queries like this to implement the fallback:

```c#
string[] locales = new[] { "fr-ca-on", "fr-ca", "fr", "" }; 
return (
   from Translation translation in reader.Get<Translation>()
   where locales.Contains(translation.Locale)
   group translation by translation.Key into translationGroup
   select translationGroup.OrderByDescending(p => p.Locale.Length).First()
   //or: select translationGroup.MaxBy(p => p.Locale.Length)
);
```

These work very well in memory, but NHibernate can't translate the group select into SQL. (It only seems to support simple aggregate methods like `.Count()`, not selects.)

How can I rewrite this query so NHibernate can translate it to SQL? I can't think of a way that doesn't involve undeferring the query into memory early, which would really hurt the application's performance.

(I'd rather not use resource files, because I have other entities which relate to the translations.)

Comment: Is using another querying API like QueryOver an option? This is quite doable in QueryOver.

Comment: I think that would be fine, though I'm not clear on the implications of mixing `.QueryOver()` and LINQ in the same session (since the application already makes heavy use of LINQ). I'll play around with it and see. Do you have a similar example I can get started with? (If not, I'll figure it out.)

Comment: I can give a pretty good example if you'll provide the SQL you ultimately want. I don't think there's a problem with mixing LINQ and QueryOver--they are both just different ways of issuing queries.

Comment: I'm not too picky about the final SQL, so long as it's reasonably efficient. Something like this would work:

`SELECT * FROM [translations] INNER JOIN (SELECT [key] AS [m_key], MAX(LEN([locale])) AS [m_localelen] FROM [translations] WHERE [locale] IN ('en-gb', 'en', '') GROUP BY [key]) AS [match] ON [key] = [m_key] AND LEN([locale]) = [m_localelen] WHERE [locale] IN ('en-gb', 'en', '')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to rewrite it as a LINQ subquery:

```c#
string[] locales = new[] { "fr-ca-on", "fr-ca", "fr", "" }; 
return (
    from Translation translation in reader.Get<Translation>()
    where
        locales.Contains(translation.Locale)
        && (translation.Locale.Length == reader
            .Get<Translation>()
            .Where(p => locales.Contains(p.Locale) && p.Key == translation.Key)
            .Max(p => p.Locale.Length)
        )
    select translation
);
```

NHibernate handles the subquery nicely and turns it into this (prettified) SQL:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [translation] translation
WHERE
    [locale] IN ('fr-ca-on', 'fr-ca', 'fr', '')
    AND LEN([locale]) = (
        SELECT CAST(MAX(LEN(sub.[locale])) AS INT)
        FROM [translation] sub
        WHERE
           sub.[locale] IN ('fr-ca-on', 'fr-ca', 'fr', '')
           AND sub.[key] = translation.[key]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really just want to implement the mentionend Get method

how about that?

```
private string Get(string key, string locale)
{
    return (from Translation t in reader
       where t.Key == key && (t.Locale == null || t.Locale == "" || locale.StartsWith(t.Locale))
       orderby t.Locale descending
       select t.Value).First();
}
```

PS: the change to 'StartsWith' makes sense depending on the locale keys you have and what you request 
exotic but the only example i can think of right now :) 'fr-ch' may give you french when requesting 'ch' (suisse german)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I need an `IQueryable<Translation>` for further querying in the application. :)